# How can i get resources from JAR file

Tags: android, jar

How can i get resources from JAR file? I include to main project JAR file, and try to call from main project resourse string from jar library like `com.jarlibrary.R.string.test`, but i have exception and main application crash.. other ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you `can't access resource from jar` file, you just put class file and access it, for resource you have to `add separately folder` of resources in your project.

Comment: I read that in the 14 version of ADT this possibility is, but google did not find examples.