# Images are not accessible using the context.getClassLoader.getResaurceAsStream from android jar in Unity plugin

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-unity-plugin

I am trying to create an SDK in which i have few images and all the classes in .jar file.

I have already created the unity plugin and bridge class for android SDK.
Functionality is working all fine in SDK.
But i am facing the below problem, I am creating all the view programetically in this SDK,

In native android it is working fine. Images are accessible using the `context.getClassLoader.getResourceAsStream` method and i get the `InputStream` of image well and image is showing when view is created.

But when i call the SDK from the unity plugin and android-bridge class i am getting `null` as `InputStream`.

Does anyone has any idea about this?
And how to solve this.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to copy your images to assets and use `getAssets().open("yourimage.jpg")`.

---

Source:

[Android files in jar library not accessible when using with Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20762092/android-files-in-jar-library-not-accessible-when-using-with-unity)

[Android files in jar library not accessible when using with Unity - Please help](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/android-files-in-jar-library-not-accessible-when-using-with-unity-please-help.219263/)